# Hide org todo state changes in drawer or properties

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How do I setup my org tree to store the TODO state changes into a drawer.  The Logbook drawer works fine.  The problem is that when i do a repeating entry each day it logs that.  Making a huge tree under the tasks.  Anyone know how to store this in :PROPERTIES: or another such drawer so that I still have this data, but it is not visible automatically?

Here is an example of it in my org file.

```
** TODO Weekly Review/Inbox Review (Planning) 
   DEADLINE: <2020-09-21 Mon ++1w>
   :PROPERTIES:
   :LAST_REPEAT: [2020-09-08 Tue 09:22]
   :Effort:   0:30
   :END:

   - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-09-08 Tue 09:22]
   - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-09-02 Wed 09:02]
```

**I *wish* this was formated like this**

```
** TODO Weekly Review/Inbox Review (Planning) 
   DEADLINE: <2020-09-21 Mon ++1w>
   :PROPERTIES:
   :LAST_REPEAT: [2020-09-08 Tue 09:22]
   :LOGTODOCHANGEDRAWER:
   - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-09-08 Tue 09:22]
   - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-09-02 Wed 09:02]
   :Effort:   0:30
   :END:
```

I don't care if it is in properties but I do not want these state changes listed 300times over again in plain text...it is very ugly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- TLDR

```
M-x customize-variable [RET] org-log-into-drawer
```

Set value of org-log-into-drawer to  "LOGBOOK"

1. Background
   After Digging through the org manual I was able to come up with a solution.  There is not an exact example within the manual, but by reading it you will likely get the understanding required to figure the solution out yourself.  As always, just read through it if you have time and make sure that it all makes sense generally. Here is a link to page that is most closely related.

https://orgmode.org/org.html#Tracking-TODO-state-changes

https://orgmode.org/org.html#Drawers

When using org-mode the style of tacking I was using for repeating tasks was habit.  In the example below I have applied that explicitly through the properties drawer.

When tracking a variable with org-habit there are 4 options for storage of logging.  Each time the todo state change happens org-habit was logging the state change 'outside of a drawer'; which means that when the item is opened all of the state changes appear in plain text.  By default this is the setup.  There are 3 options currently available.

To view these options go to customize-variable buffer for the "Org Process Group" inside of that you will find "Org Log Into Drawer" to get the todo state changes to write to the "Logbook" simply change to "logbook"
In summary we could write out the initialization file to store in logbook using:

### METHOD 1: define globally using init.el

```
;; write todo state changes into LOGBOOK drawer
(setq org-log-into-drawer “LOGBOOK”)
```

### METHOD 2: define for a specific tree

```
* TODO test
  DEADLINE: <2020-09-22 Tue ++1w>
  :PROPERTIES:
  :STYLE: habit
  :LOG_INTO_DRAWER: t
  :LAST_REPEAT: [2020-09-08 Tue 10:41]
  :END:
  :LOGBOOK:
  - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-09-08 Tue 10:41]
  - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-09-08 Tue 10:40]
  :END:
```

### Method 3

set this as provided by other contributor and both the state changes and the timer logs are placed inside the drawer.

```
;; inside init.el
(setq org-log-done t)
```

Comment: There *is* a clear resource: the Org mode [manual](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Tracking-TODO-state-changes).

Comment: yes but the default setup with org-habit and an org tree does not always result in the state changes being logged into a drawer.  That was the point of my answer.  There are built-in methods to do this, but this is not the default setting.

Comment: My objection was not to your answer (which is fine AFAICT) but to the statement that "there is no clear resource": the Org manual should always be the first and foremost resource (and you should be adding links to it in your answers wherever applicable); it does not cover everything obviously, so answers like yours are valuable in order to fill in the details that are inevitably left out of the manual. In particular, org-habits and logging state changes into a drawer are orthogonal and as I pointed out the latter subject is well covered in the manual.

Comment: I agree with your feedback.  Without manual i wouldn't be able to do much in org :) thanks for the reminder to provide references.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I too would suggest the manual, but this actually is one example I found outside the manual. I found the answer:

```
(setq org-log-done t)
```

[here](https://github.com/novoid/org-mode-workshop/blob/master/featureshow/org-mode-teaser.org#11-activating-org-mode).

Interestingly, t isn't even one of the options in the customization choices for this variable and yet it does work to put not only timelogs into the :LOGBOOK: drawer, but also state changes. Normally I go read the source code to see why that is the case, but I can't be bothered at the moment - it works. Prior to changing this myself, I was using one of the customization options of 'time to only put clocking (and not state changes) in :LOGBOOK:, but I prefer this setting to tidy things up.